# Is possible to add a frame in 3d chart?

Tags: highcharts

This is the code for **[3D Scatter Chart:](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/3d-scatter-draggable/)**

```
frame : {
        bottom : {
            size : 3,
            color : 'rgba(32,1,0,0.44)'
        },
        back : {
            size : 5,
            color : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.44)'
        },
        side : {
            size : 5,
            color : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'
        }
},
```

Is it possible to add one more side to the frame? For example:

```
frame : {
    bottom : {
        size : 3,
        color : 'rgba(32,1,0,0.44)'
    },
    back : {
        size : 5,
        color : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.44)'
    },
    side : {
        size : 5,
        color : 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'
    },
    top : {
        size : 3,
        color : 'rgba(32,1,0,0.44)'
    }
},
```

I have added colors on each side, but I want to add color on top as-well. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really possible.

According to the **[documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.options3d.frame)**, `frame` has only three properties:

- `back`
- `bottom`
- `side`

Comment: And do you think that there is another way to do what i want to do? I would like to have on the top a way to add a color (for example to add a rect?)... I don't have idea. Thanks

Comment: Not really, I don't know. If you don't get any answer in here, I would say go to the highcharts support forum and ask if there's any way to do this, but I don't think it's something trivial.

Comment: I hope that there is a way

Comment: I can confirm, that at this moment we have only 3 options, not 4. But you can post your suggestion [here](http://highcharts.uservoice.com)

Comment: one solution would be to add (or create) a rectangle that is positioned in the chart (on the top, so with y = 0) ??? is it possible? although my chart type is scatter?